# Running Keras with double precision fails

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run LeNet on Keras with double precision and it fails with an error: `TypeError: Input 'filter' of 'Conv2D' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'input'.`. The code I am using is as follows:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout,Flatten
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
import time
import tensorflow as tf
K.set_floatx('float64') # Note: the code works if we comment this line, i.e., with single precision
from mlxtend.data import mnist_data
X, y = mnist_data()
X = X.astype(np.float64)
X, y =  shuffle(X, y)
keras_model = Sequential()
keras_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1), padding='same'))
keras_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
keras_model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
keras_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
keras_model.add(Flatten())
keras_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
keras_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
keras_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
keras_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.95, decay=5e-4, nesterov=True))
keras_model.fit(X.reshape((-1, 28,28, 1)), np_utils.to_categorical(y, 10), epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

Any suggestions is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a gaming NVIDIA GPU.
You can use only `float32` or `int32`, that's all.
It's the default of TensorFlow.
This default is introduced by Tensorflow due to limitations of CUDA capable GPUs of Nvidia. [Best explanation I found here.](https://www.microway.com/knowledge-center-articles/comparison-of-nvidia-geforce-gpus-and-nvidia-tesla-gpus/) So the premium Tesla GPUs work well on `float16` and `float64` as well, but the gaming GPUs work only on `float32` and perform very bad for `float16` or `float64`.
I think we are all looking at OpenCL that is supported by AMD GPUs that are more pricey. Unfortunately OpenCL is not supported by TensorFlow as of now.

Suggestion#1:
You are stuck with float32. Forget changing it while having that hardware.

Suggestion#2:
Once you get a GPU good with float16 change to that. Machine learning doesn't require high precision above that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think this is a hardware issue. I am using K80s which have double-precision units and have verified that .cu examples invoking double-precision CuDNN kernels from command-line (without TF/Keras) works just fine.

Comment: Tensorflow did not support float 64 and float 16 until recently. It can be that you are trying float 64 where it's not yet supported or you are facing a bug in TF. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12943

Comment: I agree with you TF (atleast the version 1.5) might not have support for float64 convolution as the PR https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/12943 was not merged :( ... Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: There is OpenCL for TensorFlow available in development, you can follow the instructions here https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/getting-started-with-tensorflow